# Solve equations that give {} result with complex quantity

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to find the roots of the following equation by using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html):

```
Solve[8/(π u (-I a + γ) Sqrt[1 + 
    (h^2 v^2 u^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]) + 
    (16 (-I a + γ) (1 - Sqrt[1 + 
      (h^2 v^2 u^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]))/(h^2 π v^2 u^3) == 0, u]
```

but I did not get any result, it was only `{}`.
I redefined `(-I a + γ)` as `c` based on some instructions I found here, but I got nothing.

Comment: I tried `Reduce` in place of solve and it resulted in "False."

Comment: Trying to solve for an arbitrary `x` (to then take the limit `x->0`) `solx = Reduce[expr == x, u];` returns a message `...A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch \
cuts of Wolfram Language functions`. However one can find a solution `u==0` either by taking the limit or by looking at `Series[expr, {u, 0, 2}]`.

Comment: With; Reduce[expr == x, u], I got:
 u == -((2 (-2)^(3/4))/(Sqrt[h] Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[v] Sqrt[x]))
  Takeing the limit of this quantity gives infinity! on the other hand when I use Series[expr, {u, 0, 2}],I got SeriesData[
 u, 0, {Complex[0, 2]
     h^2 Pi^(-1) v^2 (a + Complex[0, 1] \[Gamma])^(-3)}, 1, 3, 1]. How can I extract the exactly value of u?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

A result of `{}` from `Solve` indicates that `Solve` thinks the solution set is empty. We can see that this is so, if we rationalize the left-hand side of the equation:

```
lhs = 8/(π u (-I a + γ) Sqrt[1 + (h^2 v^2 u^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]) +
  (16 (-I a + γ) (1 - Sqrt[1 + (h^2 v^2 u^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]))/(h^2 π v^2 u^3);
conjugates = lhs /. {{e_ :> e}, {r : Sqrt[_] :> -r, r : 1/Sqrt[_] :> -r}};
Times @@ conjugates // Expand // Simplify
(* -(64/(π^2 u^2 (-a^2 + h^2 u^2 v^2 - 2 I a γ + γ^2)))  *)
```

Since the numerator is a constant `64`, the equation `lhs == 0` cannot be satisfied.

One might put the terms together and set the numerator equal to zero. But this yields a result that makes `lhs` undefined:

```
Solve[Numerator@Together@eqn == 0, u]
lhs /. %
(*
  {{u -> 0}}
  {Indeterminate}
*)
```

Whether or not this can be considered a valid solution depends on whether clearing the denominator can be justified in the problem in which the equation arose.

Answer (score 0):

When you first do a few transformations by hand, you get a good result:

```
    8/(π u (-I a + γ) Sqrt[
1 + (h^2 u^2 v^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]) + (
16 (-I a + γ) (1 - Sqrt[
 1 + (h^2 u^2 v^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]))/(h^2 π u^3 v^2) == 0
```

to

```
    8/(π u (-I a + γ) Sqrt[
1 + (h^2 u^2 v^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]) == -((
16 (-I a + γ) (1 - Sqrt[
 1 + (h^2 u^2 v^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]))/(h^2 π u^3 v^2))
```

then

```
In[21]:= eqn = 
8 h^2 π u^3 v^2 == 
 FullSimplify[
  ExpandAll[(-16 (-I a + γ) (1 - Sqrt[
        1 + (h^2 u^2 v^2)/(-I a + γ)^2])) ( π u (-I a + \
 γ) Sqrt[1 + (h^2 u^2 v^2)/(-I a + γ)^2])]]

Out[21]= 8 h^2 π u^3 v^2 == 
16 π u (h^2 u^2 v^2 + (a + I γ)^2 (-1 + Sqrt[
     1 + (h^2 u^2 v^2)/(-I a + γ)^2]))

 In[22]:= Solve[eqn, u]
Out[22]= {{u -> 0}}

 In[23]:= Reduce[eqn, u]

 Out[23]= (a h v + I h v γ != 0 && u == 0) || (u != 0 && 
  a + I γ != 0 && v == 0) || (a + I γ != 0 && v == 0 &&
    u == 0) || (a v + I v γ != 0 && h == 0 && 
   u == 0) || (v != 0 && u != 0 && a + I γ != 0 && h == 0)
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your cooperation!

Comment: but I wont a solution in which all the involved quantities must take  any value except zero

Comment: This can only get fullfilled if a or \[Gamma] or both together are +or - Infinity.  Test this with Limit[ "nonzeropart of eqn",a->Infinity]